# Controller are not working in Spring

Tags: spring, jsp

I unable to understand why my controller are not redirecting to my html. Anyone can help me please?

```
WebConfig.java

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.udemy.controller" })
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

       @Bean
       public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() { 
          InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
          resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
          resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
          resolver.setSuffix("");
          return resolver;
       }
    }
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class HelloWorldController {

    public static final String EXAMPLE_VIEW = "example.html";  

   @GetMapping("/")
   public String fileUploadForm(Model model) {
      return "fileDownloadView";
   }

   @GetMapping("/helloworld")
    public String helloWorld(){
        return "helloworld";
    }
//   @RequestMapping(value="/exampleString", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   @GetMapping("/exampleString")
   public String exampleString(Model model){
       model.addAttribute("name","John");
       return EXAMPLE_VIEW;
   }

//   @RequestMapping(value="/exampleMAV", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   @GetMapping("/exampleMAV")
   public ModelAndView exampleMAV() {
       ModelAndView mav= new ModelAndView(EXAMPLE_VIEW); 
       mav.addObject("name", "Mike");
       return mav;   
   }
```

AppInitializer

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer
      extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] {};
   }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
   }
}
```

My project structure is well done. So my html and jsps, are inside of the root WEB-INF/views. Also, the anotation @ComponentScan, are detecting the controller. So, its not a problem of root. Anyone can tell me, why im am not redirecting to the .html , please..

Error says:

ADVERTENCIA: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring-mvc-download-example/WEB-INF/views/example.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: What are you doing exactly to produce this error? What is the address displayed in the address bar of your browser when this error occurs?

Comment: This is the adress im trying... http://localhost:8082/spring-mvc-download-example/example/exampleString

Comment: Can you share web.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller class, above the

```
@RequestMapping("/example")
```

Insert:

```
@Controller
```

Gonna be:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/example")
```

Comment: Sorry, @Controller anotation was implemented. however, i didnt put it in the question.

Comment: Ok, do you have some "AppInitializer"? maybe is missing something in there

Comment: No, i havent. Should i have to create a class??

Comment: Sorry im a bit tired. Yes I have a class AppInitializer. I will examinate the code. thans

Comment: Have you found the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you have to annotate class HelloWorldController with `@Controller` or `@RestController`, only then it will be picked by `@Componentscan` annotation.

Comment: put it. I forget it, to put in the question. Now question is updated

Comment: Please use proper punctuation to make your post more readable. Although I know what your answer means, your readers may not. Try giving a real code example. You can indent a block of code with 4 spaces to make it read as code. Or if it's a quick line of code or smaller snippet, use backticks (`) around it to make it look like code.

Comment: Thank you Joanna, next time I will be careful